# Xcode focus user location upon button press

Tags: xcode, swift, button, mapkit

I am working on a small map application and I wish for the map to centre the users current location on screen once the refresh button is pressed by the user. Currently I have this code, but nothing seems to happen once the button is pressed:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var location: CLLocation!
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var refresh: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBAction func refresh(sender: AnyObject) {

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.locationManager.delegate = self

    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// location delegate methods

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location = locations.last

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1))

    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)
{
    print("Error code: " + error.localizedDescription)
}
```

}

I am new to Swift so any help is appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: i think, you stop the location after 1st time getting the location. if click the refresh button at the time need to start update location call. self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P You are a genius sir, thank you.

Comment: Always welcome its my pleasure